# ErrorCode, Ti.storekit-1.6.0

Tags: app-store, titanium-mobile

I develop now using Ti.storekit-1.6.0.
(TitaniumStudio SDK-2.1.3GA)

### Description below shows the current my code

```
$btnItem1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 // 250 
var product = 'net.oratta.info.0250';
var Storekit = require('ti.storekit');
Storekit.purchase(product, function (evt) {
         switch (evt.state) {
              case Storekit.FAILED:
                      alert('ERROR: Buying failed!');
                      break;
               case Storekit.PURCHASED:
               case Storekit.RESTORED:
                      alert('Thanks!');
                      //markProductAsPurchased(product.identifier);
                      break;
          }
     });
 });
```

---

### The information of iTuensConnect has become like below

Apple ID : 567415203
Bundle ID : net.oratta.info

[In-App Purchase Summary]
Reference Name: 250 Coin
Product ID: net.oratta.info.0250
Type: Consumable

### Apple ID: 568619867

But, following kind of error coming out, it does not operate normally

> "-[__NSCFString product]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d4f7c20"

When how it does, this error can be evaded?
I request your advice.

Thanks,